# Why fork exits with non-zero in Minitest test?

Tags: ruby, fork, minitest

This is the code:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
class Foo < Minitest::Test
  def test_foo
    Process.fork do
      exit(0)
    end
    p Process.waitall
  end
end
```

This is the output:

```
$ ruby a.rb
Run options: --seed 40445

# Running:

[[41827, #<Process::Status: pid 41827 exit 1>]]
.

Finished in 0.016218s, 61.6599 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Why exit code is not zero?

The same code without Minitest works just fine:

```
Process.fork do
  exit(0)
end
p Process.waitall
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/467

> The problem is that `fork` duplicates the `at_exit` handlers of the parent process. Minitest uses `at_exit` to run the tests so you're hitting up against that. From the fork doco: "The child process can exit using `Kernel.exit!` to avoid running any `at_exit` functions."